# Preenchimento automático nome de produto

Tags: html

Gostaria que o nome do produto fosse puxado automaticamente para algumas partes do texto.

Por exemplo se o nome do produto é: Caneca preta, gostaria que no texto quando eu falasse do produto puxasse automaticamente o nome, pois existem várias cores do produto porém o texto deles é padrão, fazendo isso não precisaria ficar editando texto por texto :D

é possível fazer isso em html?

Comment: Em `html` é possivel, mas você vai precisar de [Javasscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction)

Comment: Você pode mostrar algum exemplo de o que está procurando? Porque o stack overflow sugere que os autores coloquem algum trecho de código para ajudar a quem irá responder...

Comment: *é possível fazer isso em html?* acredito que essa seja a resposta... resposta: http://prntscr.com/naqi0s :/

Comment: A pergunta carece de muitos detalhes, da forma atual não há como compreender o problema. E esse tipo de formatação de texto parece fazer mais sentido no backend da aplicação, uma vez que o conteúdo já será entregue pronto e indexado corretamente.

Answer (score 3):

Faz com `CSS`. Gambiarra por gambiarra, faz com **estilo**

```css
.p1::after{content:"gambiarra";}
```

```html
Não há a necessidade de fazer essa <span class="p1"></span>,
porque <span class="p1"></span> só deve ser feita por
especialistas em <span class="p1"></span>   Kkkkkk
```

Answer (score 1):

Em HTML puro, não, você vai precisar usar algumas outras ferramentas, como JavaScript, e também, vai ter que tirar essa informação de algum lugar, um banco de dados, por exemplo.

Isso tudo depende ainda da sua necessidade.

Comment: E como eu faria isso?

Comment: Na verdade é uma pergunta **bem** ampla, existem muitas formas de chegar nesse resultado, minha dica é que você tente começar do básico, HTML/CSS/JavaScript, para que você possa conhecer melhor as suas necessidades.

E quando você fizer isso, vão surgindo dúvidas, aí essas dúvidas, mais pontuais você traz aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Não, somente com HTML não é possível. Você precisa no mínimo de um JavaScript para puxar os textos de outro local, mas o recomendado é puxar os dados de um determinado produto do banco de dados.

Ideal é suar uma combinação de tecnologia, como HTML, JavaScript, Banco de dados e uma linguagem backend

Comment: E como eu faria isso?